# Show Nth span based on Nth list option selected

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a select list in each row.  Adjacent to the select list are spans, that need to be showing corresponding to the option selected, to provide some explanation for the chosen option.

For example:

```
In each row
    if user selects the 1st option
        Show the 1st span
```

This logic should apply to the whole table.  I have a [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hg3whbts/3/), but I cannot get the index value for each option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two separate event for this. you can simply use single event for select and do traversing to target and show desired element:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find('span').hide();           
    $(this).parent().next().find('span').eq($(this).find('option:selected').index()).show();
}).change();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Luw1dese/)**

Comment: Super-concise!  How do you get the correct span to show on first page load?  Is it because the first option is selected by default?

Comment: @EvilDr: it is beacause of triggering change using `.change();` after event declaration

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected option's index by `option:selected`

Check the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hg3whbts/4/)

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var val = that.val();
    var i = that.find('option:selected').index();
    that.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).find('span').hide().eq(i).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change','select', function(){
        var this1=$(this);
        var i=this1.find('option:selected').index();
       $(this).closest("td").next().find("span").hide(); $(this).closest("td").next().find("span:eq("+i+")").show();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hg3whbts/5/)